# Setting strategy on vector openlayer layer

Tags: openlayers-3

In Openlayers 3.9.0  I use `loader` to get a vector layer from Geoserver. Here is the code

```
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:5550/geoserver/mymap/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=mymap:mylayer&outputFormat=application/json', 
        {type: 'GET'})
        .done(      
         function(response) {
                    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON({});
                    sourceVector.addFeatures(geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response,{dataProjection :projection,featureProjection : projection}));
                })
        .fail(function () {alert("BAD");});
    },
    strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 20}))
});
```

I try to change `strategy` to `strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.bbox` but I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.strategy_ is not a function`.

Most of the examples set bbox strategy and also a BBOX on the url. If I add `....&BBOX='+extent.join(',')` at the end of the url I still get the same error. What am I missing? Is it the strategy, the url, the settings? How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not initialize a new [`ol.loadingstrategy.bbox`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html#.bbox), it is already an `ol.LoadingStrategy` (unlike `ol.loadingstrategy.tile` which is a factory returning an `ol.LoadingStrategy` based on a TileGrid.

```
// when using the bbox strategy:
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox

// when using the tile strategy:
strategy: new ol.loadingstrategy.tile(tileGrid)
```